# Javascript code not executing on modal close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal with a form that I try to clear when I close the Modal. I have 2 different Modal on 2 different pages. I use the same Javascript to clear them. On the User page, it works, but not on the AddProject page. Do you know why and how I can fix this?

```
$('#addProjectModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#addProjectModal form')[0].reset();
});

$('#addadminprofile').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   $('#addadminprofile form')[0].reset();
});
```

```
<!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="addProjectModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ajouter un projet</h5>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
         </div>
         <form action="suiviProjet.php" method="POST">
```

```
<!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="addadminprofile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Admin</h5>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
         </div>
         <form action="users.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: HINT: i suggest you to use IDs on your form then try like `$('#FORMID').trigger("reset");`

Comment: debug it and figure out what is happening. Does it find the element, is the event called? does it find the form?

Answer (score 0):

I found why one code was running and not the other ... I had to clear the cache and it's good